# PowerPoint: How to get the current slide in multi-selected slides?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I selected multi-slides in the current presentation, But I want to get the slide which in the current document view.

I tried to use the following code for getting the slide,

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

But it failed, I still got the first slide in the selected slides.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What "view" are you in when you do this? Normal? Slide Sorter? If normal, are you selecting the preview thumbnails on the left?

Comment: How to access **active slide** when the slide show is started? Getting an exception when I use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide` when the slide show is started. @ToddMain

Answer (score -1):

Create a event

```
Application.SlideSelectionChanged += Application_SlideSelectionChanged;
private void Application_SlideSelectionChanged(SlideRange SldRange)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(SldRange[1].SlideNumber);
}
```

gives u the current slideNumber in document view